# reset checkbox value ajax beginform response in mvc 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

In my application I've got an ajax beginform:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DeletePages", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "OnSuccessDelete", OnFailure = "OnFailureDelete" }, new { id = "ToolBarActionsForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="col-xs-2 list-group icon-bar">
        <a class="list-group-item delete" href="#" title="Delete selected page(s)" data-tool="Delete"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-10 thumbnailArea">

    </div>

}

 $(".delete").on("click", function () {

        $("#ToolBarActionsForm").submit();
    });
```

This form returns a partial view to thumbnailArea that has some data and checkboxes in it:

```
@model List<Doc>
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++ )
    {
            <div class="thumbnailItem">
                <div class="imageTitle">  
                    @fileName
                    @Html.HiddenFor(f => Model[i].FileName)
                    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="selectAll">Select All</button>
                </div>
                <ul class="thumbnails row">
                    @for(int p = 0; p < Model[i].DocPages.Count; p++)
                    {
                        <li class="col-xs-2">
                            <label class="control control--checkbox">
                               @Html.CheckBoxFor(pg => Model[i].DocPages[p].PageCheck)
                                <div class="control__indicator">

                                </div>
                            </label>
                      </li>
                                 //more code here 
                      }                    
                      </ul>


            </div>

    }
```

and my onSuccessDelete function:

```
function OnSuccessDelete(response) {


    var checkboxes = $(response).find('input[type="checkbox"]');

    $.each(checkboxes, function (i, val) {
        val.checked = false;
    });

    //console.log(response);
    $('.thumbnailArea').html(response);

}
```

The problem is that the checkboxes WON'T be reset. I want them to be all false in the response being returned from the ajax form. However, this is not working. Everything else works fine, just the checkboxes won't reset themselves.

Comment: You don't have any inputs with a `class="check-box"`. But what is the point of your script. If you don't want them check when the partial is loaded, then set the value of `PageCheck` to false.

Comment: Just edited the answer. but that's not what's causing the problem. also even though I set my pageCheck to false in my controller, it does not work.

Comment: What (of course it was a problem)? And if the value of each `PageCheck` property is false, then all the checkboxes will be unchecked. What is it you think your trying to do with the script?

Answer (score 0):

You must uncheck it by attr.

```js
$('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', false);
```

Comment: try this   $( "#myCheckbox" ).prop( "checked", false);